# When to replace a database column with an ID instead

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm helping a friend design a database but I'm curious if there is a general rule of thumb for the following:

**TABLE_ORDER**

- OrderNumber
- OrderType

The column OrderType has the possibility of coming from a preset list of Order Types. Should I allow VARCHAR values to be used in the OrderType column (ex. Production Order, Sales Order, etc...) Or should I separate it out into another table and have it referenced as a foreign key instead from the TABLE_ORDER as the following?:

**TABLE_ORDER**

- OrderNumber
- OrderTypeID

**TABLE_ORDER_TYPE**

- ID
- OrderType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order type list is set, and will not change, you could opt to not-make a seperate table. But in this case, do not make it `VARCHAR`, but make it an `ENUM`.

You can index this better, and you will end up with arguably the same type of database as when you make it an ID with lookup-table.

But if there is any change at all you need to add types, just go for the second. You can add an interface later, but you can easily make "get all types" kind of pages etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use another table say "ReferenceCodes" for example:

Type, Name, Description, Code

Then you can just use the Code through out the database and need not worry about the name associated to that code. If you use a name (for example order type in your case), if would be really difficult to change the name later on. This is what we actually do in our system.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, any column that can contain duplicate data should be an id or an ENUM.  This helps you make sure that the data is always internally consistent and can reduce database size as well as speed up queries.

For something like this structure, I would probably create a master_object table that you could use for multiple types.  OrderType would reference the master_object table. You could then use the same table for other data.  For example, let's say you had another table - Payments, with a column of PaymentType.  You could use the master_object table to also store the values and meta-data for that column.  This gives you quite a bit of flexibility without forcing you to create a bunch of small tables, each containing 2-10 rows.

Brian

Comment: Your first paragraph is way off-the-wall. The data integrity constraints implied by using "id"s and "ENUM"s can be implemented perfectly well without those things. Replacing every repeating column in that way isn't even likely to be possible let alone "perfect" or even sensible.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is small ( less than 10 items ) then you could choose to model it as your first but put a column constraint to limit the inputs to the values in your list. This forces the entries to belong to your list, but your list should not change often.

e.g. check order_type in ('Val1','Val2',...'Valn')

If the list will ever change, if it is used in multiple tables, you are required to support multiple languages or any other design criteria that demands variability, then create your type table (you are always safe with this choice, it is why it is the most used).

You can collect all such tables into a 'codes' table that generalizes the concept

```
CREATE TABLE Codes (
Code_Class CHARACTER VARYING(30)  NOT NULL,
Code_Name CHARACTER VARYING(30)  NOT NULL,
Code_Value_1 CHARACTER VARYING(30),
Code_Value_2 CHARACTER VARYING(30),
Code_Value_3 CHARACTER VARYING(30),
CONSTRAINT PK_Codes PRIMARY KEY (Code_Class, Code_Name)
```

);

```
insert into codes ( code_class, code_name, code_value_1 )
        values( 'STATE','New York','NY' ),
        values( 'STATE, 'California','CA'), 
        .... );
```

You can then place and UPDATE/INSERT trigger on the table.column under change that should be constrained to a list of states. Lets say an employee table has a column EMP_STATE to hold state short-forms.

The trigger would simply call a select statement like

```
SELECT code_name
     , code_value_1
  INTO v_state_name, v_state_short_name
  FROM codes
 WHERE code_class = 'STATE'
   AND code_value_1 = new.EMP_STATE;

if( not found ) then
   raise( some error to fail the trigger and the insert );
end if;
```

This can be extended to other types:

```
insert into codes ( code_class, code_name )
        values( 'ORDER_TYPE','Production' ),
        values( 'ORDER_TYPE', 'Sales'), 
        .... );

select code_name
     , code_value_1
  into v_state_name, v_state_short_name
  from codes
 where code_class = 'ORDER_TYPE'
   and code_name = 'Sales';
```

This last method, although generally applicable can be over-used. It also has the downside that you cannot use different data types (code_name, code_value_*).

The general rule of thumb: create a 'TYPE' (e.g. ORDER_TYPE) table (to hold the values you wish to constrain an attribute to for each type), use an ID as the primary key, use a single sequence to generate all such id's (for all your 'TYPE' tables). The many TYPE tables may clutter your model, but the meaning will be clear to your developers (the ultimate goal).